# Error during integration: Tag Times (variable of integration) is protected. How to solve it?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to integrate and plot the following function:

`Y[T_?NumericQ,n_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[BesselK[1,mB1/t]*(mB1/t)^(3+n/2),{mB1/t,0,mB1/T}]`

`Plot[Y[x,1],{x,0.001,1000}]`

where `mB1=1000`.
I get the following error: [image]

What's going wrong here? Is it forbidden to define an integration variable in this way? How can I arrange for it?
Thank you!

Comment: what is `t`, you need to give it a numerical value?

Comment: I think the problem is probably the `mB1/t` in your `{mB1/t, 0, mB1/T}`. I don't think you can integrate with respect to an expression, you have to integrate with respect to a variable. As it stands you're trying to integrate `1000/t` from 0 to some other limit, but that doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Ok thank you, I replaced `mB1/t` with a simple `x` and it works. 
I was confused by the requirement of the problem I am facing, but it is a trivial question indeed...